# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

While implementing a modal for dialog boxes I am getting `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ModalInstanceCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`. I have two controllers in the same .js file. The error shows up the name of the second controller.

ng-app is contained in main html file.

```
<div ng-app = "LoginApp">
  <div ng-view>
    <!-- partial will go here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular routes

```
var LoginApp = angular.module('LoginApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
LoginApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {controller: LoginCtrl, templateUrl: '/js/templates/login.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
})
```

LoginCtrl.js file

```
'use strict'

var LoginCtrl = ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', function($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.authenticate = function(){

    var loginModal = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'login-modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        modalData: function () {
          return {
              user: {
                  name: '',
                  password: ''
              }
          };
        }
      }
    });

    loginModal.result.then(function (user) {
      $log.info("My name is:" + user.name);
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  }
}];

var ModalInstanceCtrl = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'modalData', function($scope, $modalInstance, modalData){

}];
```

In the `LoginCtrl.js` file, `LoginCtrl` doesn't shows up this error but the declaration of `ModalInstanceCtrl` is undefined. Could anyone let me know why is this happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the param of `$modal.open()`, change from this:

```
...
controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
...
```

To this:

```
...
controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
...
```

Notice, no quotes for the name of the controller, because you want AngularJS to use the `ModalInstanceCtrl` variable, not a controller registered with `angular`.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the quotes, you can register `ModalInstanceCtrl` with AngularJS, like this:

```
LoginApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',  ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'modalData', function($scope, $modalInstance, modalData){
  ...
}]);
```

Either way will work.

Comment: I tried alternative way of registering the controller with angular and then use controller name with quotes 'ModalInstanceController' but it throws the same error. however the first way did worked. thanks for the clear view on this.

Comment: LoginApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'modalData', function($scope, $modalInstance, modalData){

}]);

This is what i used for the controller to register with my angular module. it worked with quotes now.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're absolutely right that you need to register on a module, I got a brain fart. Let me update the answer to benefit future readers.

Comment: this ngareq error can also happen when you place  `.when ` outside of the config like this `.config {..... }.when ('/' ....)`